# PHP: Display comma after each element except the last. Using 'for' statement and no 'implode/explode'

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have this simple for loop to echo an array:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($director); $i++) {
   echo '<a href="person.php?id='.$director[$i]["id"].'">'.$director[$i]["name"].'</a>';
}
```

The problem here is that when more than one element is in the array then I get everything echoed without any space between. I want to separate each element with a comma except the last one.

I can't use `implode` so I'm looking for another solution

Comment: Tom Haigh's answer should work. Or just remove the last character from your resulting string (but might be not such a clean way ;)).

Comment: @SilentGhost: Why did you tag this homework? If because of the statement *I cant use 'implode'* : The OP accesses an array so he needs the loop. `implode` only works when you have already an array of elements to "implode" (of course one could generate a list of the HTML beforehand and then implode but this seems unnecessary to me).

Comment: @Felix: because of the ridiculous condition not to use implode

Comment: @SilentGhost: See my previous comment, I think you judge too fast...

Comment: @felix: use of `implode` would be appropriate here, I don't see why the question needs to be limited by some unreasonable conditions.

Comment: @Silent I think he's right, this isn't homework, the OP just doesn't want to make an array so he can implode it, he prefers a for loop

Comment: I don't find the condition ridiculous, but I *do* think it might be worth re-considering, e.g. `foreach ($directors as $key => $director) { $directors[$key] = '<...>' . $director['name'] . '</...>'; } echo implode(', ', $directors);`. Since the OP expressly asked not to use `implode()`, I'm not putting it as an answer, but it might help someone else stumbling across this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work. It's better I think to call `count()` once rather than on every loop iteration.

```
$count = count($director);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   echo '<a href="person.php?id='.$director[$i]["id"].'">'.$director[$i]["name"].'</a>';

   if ($i < ($count - 1)) {
      echo ', ';
   }
}
```

Comment: Everyone always does this by checking `$i < ($count - 1);`; am I the only person who moves the check above the main echo and checks for `$i != 0`?

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: wouldn't that still give you a trailing comma?

Comment: No, you're adding leading commas instead of trailing, but it skips the first so you don't get ", stuff, stuff". `for(...) {if($i != 0) {echo ", ";} echo "stuff";}`

Answer (score 5):

A better solution is to avoid looping altogether.  I've ignored building the links for the sake of clarity.  Note that I don't believe the inability to use implode is a condition.  I believe it's a simple statement of, "I can't see how to make this work using implode, so I did it this way instead."

```
$last_entry = array_pop($director);
if(count($director) > 0) {
    echo implode(", ", $director) . " and " . $last_entry;
} else {
    echo $last_entry;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I remember PHP syntax correctly, this might also help:

```
$str = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($director); $i++) {
   $str .= '<a href="person.php?id='.$director[$i]["id"].'">'.$director[$i]["name"].'</a>, ';
}
$str = trim($str, ", ");
```

Comment: You can even `rtrim()` rather than `trim()`, so you definitely only catch trailing commas.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred method:

```
$links = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($director); $i++) {
  $links[] = '<a href="person.php?id='.$director[$i]["id"].'">' .
      $director[$i]["name"] . '</a>';
}
echo implode(', ', $links);
```

Or

```
$output = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($director); $i++) {
  if ($output) {
    $output .= ", ";
  }
  $output .= '<a href="person.php?id='.$director[$i]["id"].'">' .
      $director[$i]["name"].'</a>';
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: I tend to use this one too! :-) Nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( $i=0 ; $i < count($arr)-1 ; $i++ )
{
    echo ( $arr[$i]."," );
}
echo ( $arr[count($arr)-1] );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = count($director);
for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
    echo '<a href="person.php?id='.$director[$i]["id"].'">'.$director[$i]["name"].'</a>';
    if($i < $number - 1){
        echo ', ';
    }
}
```

Oops, I didn't  saw the reply by Tom Haigh, we came with practically the same.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? You may want to store the result of "count($director)" in a variable outside the loop so that you do not have to waste resources recalculating it each time the loop is run.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($director);$i++){
   echo '<a href="person.php?id='.$director[$i]["id"].'">'.$director[$i]["name"].'</a>';
   if($i!=count($director)-1){echo ',';}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `foreach` contains `for` :-)

```
foreach ($director as $key => $person) {
    if ($key !== 0) echo ', ';
    echo '<a href="person.php?id='.urlencode($person['id']).'">'.$person['name'].'</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// RENAMED $director to $directors

$links = '';
foreach ($directors AS $director) {
    $links .= "<a href=\"person.php?id={director['id']}\">{$director['name']}</a>";
    if (true !== empty($links)) {
        $links .= ', ';
    }
}

echo $links;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($strings as $string){
    $superstring .= $string . ', ';
}
$echostring = substr_replace($superstring ,"",-2);
echo $echostring;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 lines solution

```
// Create your Array
$cities = Array("Rome", "Florence", "Venice");

// implode them
$list = trim(implode (", ", $cities))  ;
// remove last comma
$list = substr ( $list,0 ,strlen( $list ) );

//check result
die ($list);
```

Answer (score -1):

$count =1; 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($director); $i++) { 
if ($count!=1) {
           echo  ' , ';
   }
   echo ''.$director[$i]["name"].''; 
$count++; 
}